# Defining morphisms Hom$(m, n)$ in Mat when $m$ or $n$ is $0$

Tags: matrices, category-theory

In Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter $0$ there is a problem which requires me to prove that **Mat** defined as:
$$\text{Obj(Mat)} = \mathbb{N}$$
$$Hom(n, m)=\text{The set of all m} \times n \text{ matrices with real entries}$$

is a category with composition defined as matrix multiplication.

It seems as though Aluffi includes $0$ in the natural numbers as he asks the reader to make sense of a matrix with $0$ rows or columns, however i can't think of a way to define a matrix with those conditions. I thought about using the [Empty matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Empty_matrix) but i don't think that works since it would be a morphism that isn't unique (E.g it would be in both $Hom(0, 1)$ and $Hom(0, 2)$)

In what way could you define $Hom(n, m)$ if either $m$ or $n$ were $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this a category, it is sufficient to define the morphisms to be something that satisfy the categorical axioms. That is, there ought to be an identity, and one can compose morphisms, etc.

There is a trivial way to define $\mathrm{Hom}(m,n)$ when either is $0$. Let $\mathrm{Hom}(0,0)=\{\mathrm{id}\}$ and let $\mathrm{Hom}(m,n)=\varnothing$ when some but not all of $m$ and $n$ are $0$. Then verify these axioms.

Another way is to treat matrices as linear transformations. If it is hard to imagine what a $0\times 3$ matrix is, try to figure out what are the linear maps from $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^0$. A final remark: the zero maps $\mathbb R^0\to\mathbb R^3$, $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^0$ and $\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^0$ do not coincide, because they have different domains and/or codomains. (The point is: it is up to you to decide whether make these things the same or not. If that becomes a category, it’s done!)

Comment: I don't think the homs should ever be empty in this category, the ones you've declared empty should actually be singletons.  As you suggested later, the elements of the hom-sets are essentially linear transformations, and the zero map is always linear, so should be in every hom-set.

Comment: @Christian The former example was left there for comparison, which serves as a tool to stress the point: morphisms need not to be actual maps and it is the category axioms that matter. I don’t see why one must prefer the latter over the former when they have a clear understanding of what this is all about. Maybe there is a pedagogical reason which I am not aware of; anyway, feel free to change my mind by commenting below/writing a new answer.